# Crop image in into different part

Tags: android, imageview

I want to make an app that helps the user to crop his image into the different part's so he can upload all of them into the Instagram [Like this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noutash.coolgram&hl=en_IN) 
How can I do this?

Comment: why you are repeating question the same question you asked in the morning

Comment: https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper